# Custom read line function

Tags: c, string

I tried to write a simple read_line function like following.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MSG_LEN 60

void read_line(char *,int);

int main(){
    char msg_str[MSG_LEN+1];

    read_line(msg_str,MSG_LEN);
    printf("%s\n",msg_str);

    return 0;
}

void read_line(char *str,int n){
    char ch;
    int i=0;
    while((ch = getchar()) != '\n'){
        if(i++ < n) {
            *str++ = ch;
        }
        else {
            printf("sentence is too long!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    str[i]='\0';
}
```

and it turns out like this

```
i'm felix
i'm felix?(
```

'?'and'(' just pop up!
so i tried to declare str as a character array rather than character pointer.

```
void read_line(char str[],int n){
    int i=0;
    char ch;
    while ((ch=getchar()) != '\n'){
        if(i < n)str[i++] = ch;
        else{
            printf("Sentence is too long!\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    str[i]='\0';
}
```

it success finally.

```
i'm felix
i'm felix
```

Can somebody help me to explain why the first read_line function doesn't work properly?

Comment: You're incrementing `str` inside your loop, so when the loop exits it points after the last read character: `str[i]` tries to shift it further still and out-of-bounds.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `char str[]` or `char *str`.  As a function parameter (but only as a function parameter) it turns out those two are identical.

Comment: `str[i] = '\0';` `*str = '\0';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple fix. Change `str[i]='\0'` to `*str='\0'`

If you want to use `*(str+i)` or `str[i]` does not really matter, because they are 100% equivalent, but don't mix. Understanding this equivalence is important, because this is the direct source of the bug.

I assume this is some kind of homework, but in other case, there is a function that reads a line and it's called `fgets`.

I might also mention that when used in function prototypes, `char str[]` is 100% equivalent to `char *str`.

Lastly, `ch` should be an int, because that is what `getchar()` returns. It can return EOF, which does not fit in a a `char`.

Comment: thanks klutt. your answer is really helpful. 
this is actually a exercise in c language textbook.
And i do this practice in case when i need special format read_line function in future i can adjust myself. also appreciate for pointing ch type error. i'm so careless :P